# Dropping a schedule whose name contain '.'

Tags: oracle, jobs

I was attempting to create a schedule called `MYSCHEMA.MYSCHED` in my Oracle database using SQL Developer 4.0 Early Access, and there appears to be a bug resulting in a schedule named `MYSCHEMA.` to be created.

How could I remove this schedule? This does not work:

```
EXECUTE DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_SCHEDULE('EDP_MANAGER.');
```

(results in `00931. 00000 -  "missing identifier"`)

While this:

```
EXECUTE DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_SCHEDULE('EDP_MANAGER\.');
```

results in `"invalid character"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Double quoting works:

```
EXECUTE SYS.dbms_scheduler.drop_schedule('"MYSCHEMA."');
```